# Matlab: evaluate second derivative

Tags: matlab, derivative

After I take second partial derivative of function `f`,

```
second_div = diff(f,pz,2);
```

`second_div` now should be a function of `pz` and `u`

I want to evaluate `second_div` at give `(pz,u)`. How do I do that?

---

ATTEMPTS

---

```
second_div(2,3); <- failed because second_div is a 1*1 sym
vpa(subs(second_div,pz,u_m,2,3)); <- failed
vpa(subs(second_div,(pz,u_m),(2,3))); <- failed
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See from [mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) that you substitute a list of variables in `{}`:

```
syms f pz u
f = u*pz^3
second_div = diff(f,pz,2);
subs(second_div,{pz,u},[3,4])
```

which gives `72` as expected.